# Managing multiple types of devices

Tags: android, microsoft-surface, ipad

I'm not really a sysadmin, it's more like I got asked to manage a few devices the organisation has.

We got surface gos, ipads, Andriod tablets and VR headsets. About 10 to 15 sets of each type and they are not assigned for any specific user (they are mostly for event purposes). I have been told to use a MDM or some kind of device management solution but I do have a few questions before I go requesting one.

- Can I use one account to manage each type of device? (i.e. one Ms
  account for all the surfaces, one apple id for all the iOS devices,
  one google account for all the Androids etc, and one meta account for the
  quest).
- Could I still run the same apps simultaneously on multiple devices
  with the above setup? Think the only one I can't do that is for VR
  apps from the Oculus store? But how about the others?
- If I were to use an MDM, can I do that all on one account or do I need individual accounts for each device?

Comment: Windows, iOS and Android are the standard OS supported by mostly all MDM systems. Not sure about the VR headsets, if they base on Android then they may be manageable, too. Typically you create one MDM account per device to be managed.

Comment: @Robert so I would need 10 to 15 extra email addresses for the devices?

Comment: Cross-posted to Server Fault: https://serverfault.com/q/1109671/252799

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if controlling iOS devices needs individual accounts, but if you want to control Android devices, some MDM software, like AirDroid Business, does support controlling multiple Android devices with one account, so you can use the MDM software like that.